# Getting 'SenderId mismatch' error sending Firebase FCM push notification after switching service-account.json and service account key

Tags: firebase, message, messaging

I'm working on a mobile app project for a client where I've added push notification support using Google Firebase FCM support.  I'm currently working on the Android app (and will be supporting iOS as well).  I initially set up the Firebase project with my company's account, and successfully got it working.  Then I had our company's client set up a Firebase project for this so messaging could be used with their credentials, and I got a google-services.json for their account, as well as a service account key for their account.

The project in Firebase was set up the same way, with an Android app and an iOS app.

[This example project](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex-test) has a script to help test sending messages & push notifications, along with some sample messages in JSON format, and I've been using that to test it.  It worked with the original service-account.json and service key, but after switching those out, I'm getting a "SenderId mismatch" error when trying to send a FCM.  I'm not sure why?

Comment: Hey, any solution?